# read line by line from a file in shell scripting and display lowest 2 values

Tags: linux, shell

I have created a game in which user guesses the number that is randomly created by program and on successfully guessing program asks users name and stores the user name and score in a file.
Now i want to print the name and score of 3 players who have lowest scores.

```
range=129
randNum=`expr $RANDOM % $range`     # generates a random number between 0 and 128

score=0

printf "Enter a number: "
read num

while [ $randNum -ne $num ];
do

    if [ $num -lt $randNum ]; then
        printf "Low guess"
        score=`expr $score + 1`
    else
        printf "High guess"
        score=`expr $score + 1`
    fi

    printf "\nEnter a number: "
    read num
done

read  -p "Enter your name: " name

FILE="gameScores.txt"
echo "$name     $score" >> $FILE

readFile=`cat $FILE`

# what should i do furthur to read from file sequentially and apply a condition for lowest scores
```

Comment: Probably easiest to store the numbers as array indices. Then you can expand `"${!arrayName[@]}"` to get them in order... if you really wanted to do this in only native bash for some reason, as opposed to using `sort`.

Comment: But then, if you want to do things in native bash, why are you using a (slow, expensive-to-run) external tool like `expr`? Much, **much** more efficient to use POSIX-standardized native shell math, as in `score=$((score + 1))`; that way there's no need to `fork()` off a subshell, `exec` a separate program within it, and read that program's output through a FIFO.

Comment: ...the best approach is probably the obvious one, which I mentioned as an aside in the first comment -- just using `sort`.

Comment: You should check the user input. When I enter number `x`, the while-test breaks and I get a nice score.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sort -k 2,2n gameScores.txt | head -3
```

This will sort your score file based on the scores in the second field.  You then just print out the first 3 scores, which should be your lowest scores.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where you have your readFile assignment at the end, just replace it with what I provided.  If you need to do it line by line, you can use what I provided and pipe it through a while read loop.

Comment: what does 2,2n mean here. I know that -k is for sorting a file by key. But what about the these numbers 2, 2n ?

Comment: Use only the second field as the key, and treat it as numbers

Comment: first 2 is for 2nd field and 2n is for numbers ? Is that so ?

Comment: Per sort man page, 2,2 are the start and stop fields and the "n" is the type.  So, start on field 2, end on field 2, and sort is of type numeric.